# Vuetify theme background doesn't apply on the second component

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, themes, vuetify.js

I'm learning Vue.js with Vuetify and I'm having a problem with the themes in components.
I'm building my app as each section as a separated component that are brought together in the App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <NavBar />
    <v-main>
      <Title />
      <About />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from "./components/navbar.vue";
import Title from "./sections/Title.vue";
import About from "./sections/About.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {
    NavBar,
    Title,
    About,
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>
```

NavBar and Title are working as expected. But the About is with a white background.
I set the theme to dark in the vuetify.js, so it ends up with the Title section with a dark background but the About section with a white background.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework';

Vue.use(Vuetify);


export default new Vuetify({
    theme: { dark: true },
});
```

The title and about vues are as follows:

Title.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container id="title" fill-height class="pt-16 mt-16">
    <v-row align="center" class="white--text mx-auto" justify="center">
      <v-col class="white--text text-center" cols="12" tag="h1">
        <Logo />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-btn
        :ripple="false"
        color="transparent"
        id="no-background-hover"
        elevation="0"
        @click="$vuetify.goTo('#about-me')"
      >
        <v-icon> mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import Logo from "../components/logo.vue";

export default {
  name: "Title",
  components: {
    Logo,
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
#no-background-hover::before
  background-color: transparent !important
</style>
```

About.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container id="about-me" fill-height class="">
    <v-row>
      <v-col>Hello World</v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "About",
};
</script>
```

When I switch the positions of Title and About, then About gets the dark background while Title gets a white background.
I want both to have the same Dark Background.
What is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try to have a single `<v-container>` and place your components inside that. This might help.

Comment: @Chin.Udara Thanks, it worked. I guess vuetify can only have one main `v-container` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chin.Udara helped on it.
I just added a v-container around the sections and everything got the theme right.
But at the same time now the fill-height for the sections to fill the entire screen doesn't work anymore and I need to use a style css with `height:100vh`.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <FAButton />
    <NavBar />
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <Title />
        <About />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from "./components/navbar.vue";
import FAButton from "./components/floatingbutton.vue";
import Title from "./sections/Title.vue";
import About from "./sections/About.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {
    NavBar,
    FAButton,
    Title,
    About,
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>
```

Title.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container id="title" fill-height style="height: 100vh">
    <v-row align="center" justify="center">
      <v-col cols="12">
        <Logo />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import Logo from "../components/logo.vue";

export default {
  name: "Title",
  components: {
    Logo,
  },
};
</script>
```